# How to highlight the navigation bar in master page?

Tags: asp.net

Home

Add Contact

Upload Contact

Send Mail

Export Contact

how to highlight the each link when it click???

Comment: stackoverflow is not a site for tutorials or "Show me da codez!". Show some efforts. What have you tried so far? If you are stuck at any point then people here can help you.

Comment: Are you using `master page`? Give for information regarding your issue.

Answer (score 2):

I hope the menu links in your `master page` are something like below.

### `Master Page`

```
<ul>
  <li>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnHome" runat="server" 
           PostBackUrl="~/Home.aspx">HOME</asp:LinkButton>
  </li>
  <li>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnAdd" runat="server" 
           PostBackUrl="~/Add.aspx">Add Contact</asp:LinkButton>
  </li>
  <li>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnUpload" runat="server" 
           PostBackUrl="~/Upload.aspx">Upload Contact</asp:LinkButton>
  </li>
  <li>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnSend" runat="server" 
           PostBackUrl="~/Send.aspx">Send Mail</asp:LinkButton>
  </li>
  <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnExport" runat="server" 
           PostBackUrl="~/Export.aspx">Export Contact</asp:LinkButton>
  </li>
```

Then find each `LinkButton` in the content page and give the style using `JavaScript`.
Add the following `JavaScript` to all the `content Pages`.

### `Home Page`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var link = document.getElementById('<%=Master.FindControl("lbtnHome").ClientID %>');
  link.style.color = '#3851bc';
</script>
```

---

### `Add Contact`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var link = document.getElementById('<%=Master.FindControl("lbtnAdd").ClientID %>');
  link.style.color = '#3851bc';
</script>
```

Like the same for all other pages.
Change the color according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new css class with the new styles which should apply to menu item when on click.
e.g.

```
 .active{
 background-color:red; // example
 }
```

Then add a javascript function which se that styles in onClick.set it as onClientClick to all menu items. In the JS function you should set the css class you created to the menu item.
you can do it like this.

```
document.getElementById("YourElement").className = "active";
```